# How to set the format of the marginal graph in dash plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a scatterplot with a `marginal_y` subgraph made with:

```py
fig = px.scatter(df_filtrada, 
                 x=df_filtrada.index, 
                 y=pto, 
                 marginal_y = "violin")
```

When I update some properties of the main graph such as the background color it affects the background of the marginal subgraph as well such as the background color:

```
fig.layout.paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
fig.layout.plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
```

However, I haven't managed to remove the grid of the marginal axis:
[image]

How can I format the `marginal_y` chart properties such as the `show_grid` property? And can other properties be adjusted as well such as the title?

Comment: Did you use `make_subplots` and `add_trace` to create your subplots? The [plotly subplot documentation](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#customizing-subplot-axes) mentions you can access the subplots properties like this: `fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, row=1, col=2)`, and the subplot titles like this: `fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2") )`

Comment: Do you want to remove the grid of violin plots on the right side? Is there anything else you would like to achieve? And if you make the template darker, the visuals will be taken into account to look good. `fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark')`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the prompt replies. I updated the question to specify that I created the marginal axis using marginal_y = "violin". @mnikley, I have tried your suggested solution and it worked, I didn't realize that plotly treats it like a subplot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotly handles `marginal_x`, `marginal_y` axis as subplots.

Thus their layout can be adjusted by explicitly specifying the subplot nr to be updated. In this case the marginal axis is in `row=1`, `col=2`:

```
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, row=1, col=2)
fig.update_yaxes(zeroline=False, row=1, col=2)
```

Credit to mnikley, r-beginners for providing the answer in the comments.